# Docker fake localhost access for any LAN device

Tags: docker

After many failed attemps I am asking here. Not a programming question per say but I believe relevant to the community.

I have been trying to access my `docker-compose` dev website from my phone on LAN like this `https://lan_server_ip:8000`  (for CSS checking) but I am running into all sorts of issues and would like to know if there is a simple proxy type solution that would allow me to access my development server from LAN.

main issue is that my symfony app only recognizes a single trusted ip 127.0.0.1 set within the app itself.
I need a solution without having to modify the symfony app since adding ips for devices is unpractical; especially with dynamic ip.

The idea would be to have an interface to connect to instead of main nginx that would make the website believe that all requests are coming from the host machine 127.0.0.1.
Or modify my `nginx` configuration with a new server or location ? I tried rewriting headers but no success so far.

At the moment using responsive design on browsers but it is far from accurate and up to date. My only real solution is to find issues from the production website.

I believe adding a new container to take care of this but how ?

my `docker-compose.yaml`

```
version: "3"
services:

  nginx:
    container_name: nginx
    image: "${NGINX_IMAGE}"
    build: build/nginx
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8000:443"
    volumes:
      - "${APP_HOST_NGINX_CONF}:${APP_CONTAINER_NGINX_CONF}:ro"
      - "${APP_HOST_CERTS}:${APP_CONTAINER_CERTS}"
      - "${APP_HOST_DIR}/public:${APP_CONTAINER_DIR}/public:ro"
      - "/etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro"
    networks:
      app_network:
    depends_on:
      - app

  app:
    container_name: app
    image: "${APP_IMAGE}"
    restart: always
    build: build/app
    env_file: .env
    networks:
      app_network:
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: ${APP_HOST_DIR}
        target: ${APP_CONTAINER_DIR}
      - type: bind
        source: ${PHP_INI}
        target: /usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/localtime
        target: /etc/localtime:ro
    depends_on:
      - database

  database:
    container_name: mariadb
    image: "mariadb:${MARIADB_VERSION}"
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - "${SQL_INIT}:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d"
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_DATA_DIR}
        target: /var/lib/mysql
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_LOG_DIR}
        target: /var/logs/mysql
      - type: bind
        source: ${MARIADB_CERTS_DIR}
        target: /etc/certs/
      - type: bind
        source: /etc/localtime
        target: /etc/localtime:ro
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      app_network:
    command: [  
                "mysqld",
                "--character-set-server=utf8mb4",
                "--collation-server=utf8mb4_general_ci",
                "--require_secure_transport=OFF",
                "--bind-address=0.0.0.0",
                "--ssl-key=/etc/certs/server-key.pem",
                "--ssl-cert=/etc/certs/server-cert.pem",
                "--ssl-ca=/etc/certs/ca-cert.pem",
              ]

networks:
  app_network:
```

`nginx.conf`

```
#./images/nginx/build/default.conf
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name _;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name  127.0.0.1;
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/certs/dev.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/certs/dev.key;
    index index.php index.html;
    root /var/www/app/public;

    client_max_body_size 128M;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$query_string;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass app:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    error_log /var/log/nginx/app.error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/app.access.log;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, because it is probably a non sense, but why don't expose your app container directly? I mean, using something like `ports: - "9000:9000"` in your `app` service definition in your docker compose file. Again sorry, please, because probably I am not understanding your question.

Comment: I have to connect from `NGINX`. I have tried connecting to `https//ip:8000`; problem is my app is crashing because of "untrusted hosts" issues. I can't be adding new trusted hosts for all my lan devices. I just want a man in the middle type of container to fake 127.0.0.1 to my website. I hope this clarifies

Comment: Have you tried adding your LAN server IP to server_name on the 443 server from nginx.conf? Something like **server_name 127.0.0.1 192.168.1.123;**.

Comment: @Anton no but even if this worked it would not be a solution since I can't constantly modify nginx conf or want to set a static ip for my laptop

Comment: @Sam and what about **server_name _;**?

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback @Sam. And, what header are you using to identify the client IP? By your configuration, I think you should be receiving the nginx container IP address as the remote one? Is that right? Please, could you elaborate how are you restricting the range of trusted IP addresses?

Comment: @jccampanero the trusted ip range is set within the Symfony app settings in `framework.yaml`. It should not be edited. I have `127.0.0.1` for dev and my server ip for prod. The solution should be app agnostic. Entrypoint is Nginx only;

Comment: @Anton I am not understanding what you are asking. I never modified nginx server_name if that is what you are asking. it is 127.0.0.1 for dev and different for prod

Comment: Have you looked into `ngrok` ?

Comment: @Paulo no but looks promising so I will probably try if no native solution is found. ngrok is a signup service and Im not a big fan of this

Comment: Sorry for the late reply @Sam.  Thank you very much for the feedback. I am sorry because I am not very familiar with Sympony. In any case, I reviewed the documentation of the library searching for some background. Well, perhaps one last thing you could try is providing, in dev only, a different `Host` header to your app.  When using fastcgi, you could try providing something like `fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST 127.0.0.1` as one configuration line in the `location ~ \.php$` block in your nginx configuration, for instance, right after `fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;`. I haven't tested the

Comment: solution but I think it could be worth value to test. I hope it helps.

Comment: @jccampanero I tried your suggestion and got invalid nginx configuration. I agree there must ba way to rewrite headers but no luck yet

Comment: I am very sorry to hear that it didn't working properly @Sam. Probably the variable doesn't exist: as I could read, it seems to be only available on certain systems. Out of curiosity, what error did nginx report? In any way, I don't want to disturb you any more mate, I hope you find an answer to the problem.

Comment: If symphony server is binding to localhost then you won't be able to connect from nginx to symphony because the request will come from a different IP even though it's within the same docker network

Comment: @jccampanero actually you are a genius; it worked. I had invalid conf because I forgot `;` at the end of the line ! Please post solution if you want to claim bounty. You really helped me there in my development workflow. Thank you

Comment: That is great @Sam!! I am glad to hear that the proposed solution worked and, especially, that it really helped you in your development workflow., that is fantastic!! Thank you very much, I will post an answer with the proposed approach: in any case, honestly, the only important think if that you were able to solve the problem, that is the real bounty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not an expert in Symphony and the trusted hosts mechanism you described
in your question comments but, if the actual problem is simulating that your requests are coming from `127.0.0.1`, you could try configuring `nginx` to provide that value in the `Host` header when proxying your application.

Using FastCGI you could obtain the desired result including the following line within the `location ~ \.php$` block in your `nginx` configuration:

```yaml
fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST 127.0.0.1;
```

For example:

```yaml
location ~ \.php$ {
  try_files $uri =404;
  fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
  fastcgi_pass app:9000;
  fastcgi_index index.php;
  include fastcgi_params;
  fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
  fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
  fastcgi_param HTTP_HOST 127.0.0.1;
}
```

Please, take my words with caution: as I said, I don't fully understand Symphony and I don't want to cause you any kind of problem.